# Return a private node using public function

Tags: c++, class, nodes, abstract-data-type

I have a class :

```
class HashTable {
public:
     .....

private:
    struct Node {
        Data    aData;
        Node    *next = NULL;
    };
};
```

How can I make a public member function to return data of type Node ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can just make a public member function to return data of type Node. if you run into problems doing that, you could ask for help.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. A `private class` is to be used only for implementation. If it is to be returned by a `public` member function, it needs to be in the `public` section of the class.